# No supported authentication methods available - connecting to FreeBSD using PuTTY

Tags: ssh, freebsd, users, putty

I have created an EC2 instance that runs FreeBSD, and I can log into it using my SSH key and the default user ec2-user. I logged into it, and switched to root using su. I then created a personal account using adduser, and enabled password authentication and typed in a password.

When I tried to log into my account using PuTTY, I got the error "No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)".

I have already enabled password authentication using `PasswordAuthentication yes` in my sshd config.

Comment: Did you restart the `sshd` service after changing the config?

Comment: yes. (insert filler text here so i can make a comment)

Comment: Check for clues in the EC2 instance's /var/log/auth.log. FWIW, I have never needed `PasswordAuthentication yes`. FreeBSD's default sshd configuration defaults to PAM-based authentication, which includes password auth and public key auth. Also, you can test by ssh-ing from the instance to the instance.  Login as ec2-user, then say `$ ssh myaccount@localhost` or some other appropriate hostname instead of localhost.  Perhaps the FreeBSD ssh client will give you more useful debugging output than Putty does.

Comment: Just checked auth.log, this is what it said when I tried to auth: Apr 17 02:27:16 freebsd sshd[57154]: user wmin login class  [preauth]
Apr 17 02:27:16 freebsd syslogd: last message repeated 1 times
Apr 17 02:27:16 freebsd sshd[57154]: error: Received disconnect from *my ip address* port 59670:14: No supported authentication methods available [preauth]
Apr 17 02:27:16 freebsd sshd[57154]: Disconnected from authenticating user wmin *my ip address* port 59670 [preauth]

Comment: FreeBSD client shows the same thing:
wmin@localhost: Permission denied (publickey).